# "compdef: unknown command or service" with disk quota exceeded

Tags: zsh, disk-usage, autocomplete

I just came across a problem with zsh.

Every time I open it, I got this:

```
/home/****/.zcompdump:201: parse error near `\n'
compdef: unknown command or service: git
```

And zsh completion broke down as well, which is really annoying.

```
$rm -f ~/.zcompdump*; compinit 
compdump:print:124: write error: disk quota exceeded
```

Removing zcompdump does work for me, but I have to **type it every time** or next time when I open terminal it fails again.

In ~/.zshrc file, I see "plugins=(git)".  I wonder if it's related with the zsh problem.

Comment: Going by the second error message, it looks like your account's allotted quota of disk space is full. Meaning, your account is not allowed to write any more data onto the filesystem. You should be able to check your quota with the [`quota`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/quota) command.

Answer (score 0):

`.zcompdump` is a cache of the configuration of the completion system. If you have it, zsh starts faster.

Your problem is that you've just about reached your disk quota. When zsh tries to write the `.zcompdump` file, it fails midway because you aren't allowed to write anymore. Then, when it reads the corrupt file back, trouble ensues.

You can prevent zsh from using a `.zcompdump` file by editing your `.zshrc` and adding the `-D` option to the `compinit` call. Alternatively, you can use a different location, e.g.

```
compinit -u -d /tmp/luca/.zcompdump
```

That's assuming you manage to save the edited version of `.zshrc`! You should really delete a few files from your account to get more free space.